# When a liquid is compressed with 4 pistons with pressure P, will the pressure increase by 4P or P? And Why?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure

This question in a book confused me and my friends a lot:

[image]

The answer given is (A) but we are not able to understand how. We asked a lot of teachers and consulted many books but didn't get any satisfactory answer. This is very counterintuitive. Please explain in detail why don't the other pistons affect the pressure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was 4P they would all be pushed out, because they would have 4x pushing out compared to in.

Comment: Ah yes I somewhat get your point .. the force of the piston needs to be in eqm with the force of the water .. However since this question has caused a lot of confusion, can you show a detailed analysis of the forces here?

Comment: Elegant answer.

Comment: @Kartik The problem reads "an additional force $F$ is applied to *each* piston*" (emph. added). Each piston has area $A$, and pressure is force applied to a distributed area. Free-body diagrams can be used to show that the pressure is identical at every point within the container, i.e., directly adjacent to each piston and at the center of the chamber.

Comment: Also recall that pressure is an [intensive variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties#Intensive_properties); not an extensive one; two applications of pressure $P$ at different spatial locations at the same time gives $P$, not $2P$. Again, free-body diagrams may be useful to convince yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Pressure is defined as F/A, and as a result, change in pressure will be $\Delta P = \Delta F / A$.  The change in force is 4F, and the total area over which that change in pressure acts is 4A.  Thus, the change in pressure is going to be $\Delta P = 4F / 4A = F/A$.